# How to add all rule to process task A (then) -> task B

Tags: makefile

I have

```
todo:   $(SRC)
    $(CC) -o todo $^ $(CFLAGS)

ctodo:  $(LIBS)
    $(CC) ${INCLUDES} -c -o todo.a $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

I want to have some kind of `all` by default which will build library first and todo after it.

alike **all: ctodo -> todo** (in pseudocode) How to make it?

Comment: Why do you want to build the library first? Does `todo` need it?

Comment: @Beta not yet, but in future it will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but in general the way to get Make to execute rules in order is to make one a prerequisite of another:

```
.PHONY: all
all: todo

todo: $(SRC) | ctodo
$(CC) -o todo $^ $(CFLAGS)

ctodo:  $(LIBS)
$(CC) ${INCLUDES} -c -o todo.a $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

(I've used the `|` so that `ctodo` won't show up in `$^`.)

Comment: For the curious, the `|` syntax for order-only prerequisites is defined in [Types of Prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) in the GNU Make manual.